how to distinguish negative shock or positive shock in TGARCH model?

IN the picture, how to know whether the yellow highlighted part exists or not?
because the return of day 1000 drop from 0.02 to 0.01, so there was a negative shock, so l should keep the yellow highlighted part in the calculation of VAR? am l right? so many thanks
